# How to write a custom comparator with custom sort in Python3 to use it in sorted() function

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, comparator

I'm currently stuck on a problem to write a comparator. The base idea was to write a function, which takes to parameters (two lists), but I want to use it on a list of these lists to use it in sorted() function. How shall I do it?

Comparator:

```py
def dispersion_sort(frec, srec):

    if isinstance(frec, intervals.Interval) and isinstance(srec, intervals.Interval):
        if frec[DOUBLE_RES_COL] < srec[DOUBLE_RES_COL]:
            return frec
        if frec[DOUBLE_RES_COL] > srec[DOUBLE_RES_COL]:
            return srec
        if frec[DOUBLE_RES_COL].overlaps(srec[DOUBLE_RES_COL]):
            if (frec[DOUBLE_TIME_COL] < srec[DOUBLE_TIME_COL]):
                return frec
            else:
                return srec

    return frec
```

Sample `frec` data:
`['1', 'Mikhail Nitenko', '@login', '✅', [-0.000509228437634554,0.0007110924383354339], datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 2, 14, 46, 46)]`

How I wanted to call it:

```py
results = sorted(results, key=dispersion_sort)
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cmp_to_key) what you're looking for?

Comment: so what's the issue, also provide some sample data and expected output. also if you are using custom objects please show the definitions of those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`functools.cmp_to_key`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cmp_to_key) for this:

```
from functools import cmp_to_key

results = sorted(results, key=cmp_to_key(dispersion_sort))
```

It will transform the old style comparator function (which takes two arguments), into a new style key function (which takes one argument).

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to explicitly create a comparator, you'd want to implement a custom class that has that has these magic methods:

```py
class comparator:
        def __init__(self, obj, *args):
            self.obj = obj
        def __lt__(self, other):
            return mycmp(self.obj, other.obj) < 0
        def __gt__(self, other):
            return mycmp(self.obj, other.obj) > 0
        def __eq__(self, other):
            return mycmp(self.obj, other.obj) == 0
        def __le__(self, other):
            return mycmp(self.obj, other.obj) <= 0
        def __ge__(self, other):
            return mycmp(self.obj, other.obj) >= 0
        def __ne__(self, other):
            return mycmp(self.obj, other.obj) != 0
```

Here, the function `mycmp` is a function like the one you showed. You can also choose to put your logic directly in the class itself. Here, these methods should return a `True` or `False`, which is different from your current function. Make sure that is changed accordingly if you want to use the current function directly into this class template.

Once you have the class ready , you can pass it in directly: `key=comparator`